# dd: copy N first bytes of each M-sized block

Tags: sh, dd

Given a binary input file made of data blocks which are N bytes long, how can I extract the first M first bytes of each block using `dd`?

for example, with M=10 and N=8, the data could look like this:

```
$ M=10
$ head -c $(( M * 5 )) /dev/urandom \
  | tee inputfile.bin \
  | hexdump -e '"%07.7_Ax\n"' -e "\"%07.7_ax \" ${M}/1 \"%02x \" \"\n\""
0000000 c0 07 5d 59 dc 03 2e 38 49 c4
000000a ca ad 44 6d 09 61 2b 6c 7c ba
0000014 c4 96 c6 73 8b ed 42 cf d9 9c
000001e 49 b7 bb ea 32 dc 35 6a 5c d8
0000028 55 15 a0 aa d5 aa 60 2c 30 de
0000032
```

and I would like to extract this from the input:

```
$ N=8
$ hexdump -e '"%07.7_Ax\n"' -e "\"%07.7_ax \" ${N}/1 \"%02x \" \"\n\"" output.bin
0000000 c0 07 5d 59 dc 03 2e 38
0000008 ca ad 44 6d 09 61 2b 6c
0000010 c4 96 c6 73 8b ed 42 cf
0000018 49 b7 bb ea 32 dc 35 6a
0000020 55 15 a0 aa d5 aa 60 2c
0000028
```

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/957724/perform-dd-from-input-file-excluding-last-4-bytes-of-every-block

Comment: Why do you expect `dd` to be able to do this? You can read the file again and again to extract one fragment at a time but that's hugely inefficient.